# CMake error - Cannot detect libjpeg and ADD_SUBDIRECTORY() error

Tags: windows, cmake

I am building Podofo in Windows using CMake and Visual Studio and have these 2 problems.

One is CMake cannot detect libjpeg.

> CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:312 (FIND_PACKAGE):   By not providing
>   "FindLIBJPEG.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has   asked
>   CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "LIBJPEG", but 
>   CMake did not find one.
>
> Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LIBJPEG"
>   with any   of the following names:
>
> ```
> LIBJPEGConfig.cmake
> libjpeg-config.cmake
> ```
>
> Add the installation prefix of "LIBJPEG" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
>   "LIBJPEG_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
>   "LIBJPEG" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
>   has   been installed.
>
> Libjpeg not found. JPEG support will be disabled

While I already set commands in build.cmd file as below:

```
    set LIBJPEG_DIR=D:\jpeg-9
    cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..\podofo-src -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="%LIBJPEG_DIR%" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="%LIBJPEG_DIR%" -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=FALSE -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG=freetype245_D -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE=freetype245MT
```

All the LIBJPEG files are all in d:\jpeg-9, header files and lib files. Why Cmake still cannot detect LIBJPEG?

Another problem is I got error as below while running CMake.

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:502 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
>   add_subdirectory given source "src" which is not an existing
>   directory.

so I searched CMakeLists.txt and found below command:

```
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

What cause this error? How to avoid the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To get CMake to find libjpeg, you want to set [`CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) to D:\jpeg-9 rather than either [`CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH) or [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH).  If D:\jpeg-9\libjpeg-config.cmake exists, the [`find_package`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_package) should then pick it up.

As to your second problem, it looks like you have a corrupt source tree.  `ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)` would require a directory called "src" to exist in the same folder as the CMakeLists.txt (probably the root folder?)  Perhaps a fresh download / checkout would help here.